# Indicator broken on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gtk3, appindicator

I have written a simple indicator applet for Ubuntu in python with gi.repository which I had been running successfully on my Ubuntu 14.04 for a long time without any problems. After I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 I started seeing some weird behavior. I tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 again just to be sure and it works fine but on Ubuntu 16.04 my menu events don't get fired and the application sometimes doesn't respond when I'm trying to change the icon.

Some basic code indicator that works on Ubuntu 14.04 but not on Ubuntu 16.04

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(
        'mytestindicator',
        gtk.STOCK_INFO,
        appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES
    )
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    gtk.main()

def quit(source):
    gtk.main_quit()

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    item_quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit.connect('activate', quit)
    menu.append(item_quit)
    menu.show_all()
    return menu

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So my question is what changed between Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and how can I create a reliable indicator applet that runs smoothly on both systems?

One thing I noticed though, on Ubuntu 14 I have gi.repository version 3.12.0 but on Ubuntu 16 it's 3.20.0, not sure that matters though.

Comment: What is the weird behavior?

Comment: Menu events don't get fired and the application sometimes doesn't respond when I'm trying to change the icon

Comment: Just clicking the Quit menu item in the code I posted above has no effect. Most of the time it actually works but like 25% of the time when I run the app the indicator and its menus are just completely unresponsive

Comment: Put that explanation in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Barmar It's actually in the question

Comment: It works well on Mint 18. This problem comes up regularly on Ubuntu 16.04 'my Gtk program does not work properly'. You might need to switch to a different window manager / distro.

Comment: @theGtknerd do you have any references or links where I can read about such problems? If anyone can point me to something that might help I would be very grateful

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=Ng3yWd6dHebGjwTg4KP4CQ&q=ubuntu+16.04+gtk+not+working+stackoverflow&oq=ubuntu+16.04+gtk+not+working+stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23690.27718.0.27998.14.14.0.0.0.0.263.2233.0j7j5.12.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.8.1504...33i160k1j33i21k1.0.n8U0Y31PLwQ

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=qA3yWcyjNqvIjwT3o4uwDg&q=ubuntu+16.04+gtk+app+not+working&oq=ubuntu+16.04+gtk+app+not+working&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6285.7013.0.7301.4.4.0.0.0.0.234.567.0j1j2.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.233...35i39k1.0.JTV4lGHT9ro

Comment: @theGtknerd Okay so gtk3 is broken on Ubuntu 16, that's good to know. Do you happen to know how I can create a panel indicator without it? with gtk2 perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157618/discussion-between-thegtknerd-and-logileifs).

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk, Gio, GLib, AppIndicator3, Notify
import os, sys

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'Resource phone logger'

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, menu):

        menuitem_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        menuitem_quit.connect('activate', Gtk.main_quit)
        menu.append(menuitem_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        menu.connect('button-release-event', self.menu_button_release_event)


    def menu_button_release_event (self, menu, event):
        #code to only show left click
        if event.button == 3:
            menu.show()
        else:
            print ("show")
            menu.hide()

def main():
    Notify.init(APPINDICATOR_ID)
    image = os.path.abspath('posting.svg')
    indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, image, AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)  
    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    indicator.set_menu(menu)
    app = GUI(menu)
    Gtk.main()
    Notify.uninit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```